# Why use an "edit" url for an account activation email in a rails mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, railstutorial.org

I'm at the point in the Hartl tutorial ([chapter 11.2.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#sec-mailer_templates)) where you create an account activation mailer and I was wondering, why are we creating an "edit" url like this:

```
<%= edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>

http://www.example.com/account_activations/q5lt38hQDc_959PVoo6b7A/edit
```

It seems like "edit" is not the right word for this. To me it would make more sense to use a method called something like "activate" instead "edit".

Why is Hartl using "edit"? I suspect it's because that is RESTful way to do it? Such as in this `edit_user_url(user)`.

Here are the routes that the mailer is using:

```
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

Can anyone explain why he might be using "edit"?

Comment: we couldnot access this tutorial. It's asking for login. Can you please tell us what routes you used in this?

Comment: I found a public version of the book and updated the link. Also edited the question to add the routes.

Comment: `edit` simply follows the REST conventions. You can edit your routes and name it whatever you want as long as you know what you're doing. Maybe this additional step was a little outside the intentions of the chapter

Comment: Yes, its rails way to define routes if you are defining routes using `resources`. You can read more information from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions. If you don't want this type of URLs then add each URL manually like this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code

Answer (score 1):

Well practically activation of account, changes it. So from rest point of view you editing it.

If you want to be more verbose in terms of purpose, you could alias this route to *activate* using `as` method [:as documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: Ok. That's what I suspected. I guess I was thinking that I'm not editing the "account activation", I'm editing the user. I'm changing the boolean on the user model called "activate" from false to "true" on the user model. So to me that seems as if I'm editing the user, not "account_activation".